# How to create html tag in jsp page from java bean object

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm trying to create jsp page that contains chart and tool tip on the chart.
I got to this point:
I have a chart as image in my jsp page.
I have String that contians the html tag map with all the data about the tool tip.

I am looking for a way to take the String with all the data and put it in my jsp page as regular html tag.

I tried to use :

```
<h:graphicImage id="linkGraph"
                value="#{myBean.fileName}"
        usemap="#{myBean.mapPath}"
        width="#{myBean.width}"
        height="#{myBean.height}"
        rendered="true"
        style="border-color: #ffffff;/>
        #{myBean.mapHtml}
```

I'm getting it as text in my jsp page

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the correct headers in your JSP, i,e:

```
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="[taglib url]" %>
```

EDIT:

To enable Expression Language:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Then get your bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="fully.qualified.bean.class.MyBean"/>
```

And then use it in your tag:

```
<h:graphicImage id="linkGraph"
            value="${myBean.fileName}"
    usemap="${myBean.mapPath}"
    width="${myBean.width}"
    height="${myBean.height}"
    rendered="true"
    style="border-color: #ffffff;/>
    ${myBean.mapHtml}
```

Note the ${byBean.property} expressions, with a $ not a #: your bean class needs matching getter methods, i.e. getFilename(), getMapPath() etc.

Comment: yes, i did, i'm looking for a way to take String from my bean and create html code from it

Comment: I already have a bean, all the logic in it, i can't create a new bean

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.
Create simple tag(div, span....) with id="tag"
and with the help of java script function

```
        function replaceString(str) {
        document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = str;
    }
```